# Export text content from complex LaTeX document

Tags: biblatex, export

I have a large and complex LaTeX document (XeLaTeX) with multisection bibliorgaphy (biblatex). I want to export resulting text content into plain text. Output from `pdf2text` and similar tools contains additional new lines and hyphens. I can't use `detex` or similar tool also, because I need a complete bibliography.

The only idea that I have is export document with very large page size (one line per paragraph) and make `pdf2text` after (see MWE). There may be a more elegant solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[paperwidth=50in, paperheight=8.5in, left=1in]{geometry}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}

@ARTICLE{Reitman2015,
     author = {Reitman, N. G. and Bennett, S. E. and Gold, R. D. and Briggs, R. W. and DuRoss, C. B.},
      title = {Транзитная фотомозаика высокого разрешения из моделирования на основе изображений: анализ рабочих процессов и ошибок},
    journal = {Bulletin of the Seismological Society of America},
       year = {2015},
     volume = {105},
      pages = {2354-2366}
}


\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}

Проверка

\thispagestyle{empty}

\nocite{Reitman2015}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: You can convert you document to HTML using tex4ht, then convert the HTML file to text. Try make4ht -ux filename.tex

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! In first look it works, but in all non-latin characters is absent in output of `make4ht -ux file.tex` (MWE updated - some cyrrilic characters added).

Comment: @StanislavIvanov I've posted an answer that fixes this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your document to HTML and then convert the HTML file to text. TeX4ht supports both XeLaTeX and BibLaTeX, but it needs to be configured in order to support non-Latin alphabets.

Save the following code as `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\xeuniuseblock{Cyrillic}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\xeuniuseblock` command loads declarations for Unicode characters for the given [Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block). You will need similar commands for Greek or Arabic, if you have them in the bibliography.

The conversion can be done using the following commands:

```
make4ht -uxm draft -c myconfig.cfg filename.tex
biber filename
make4ht -uxm draft -c myconfig.cfg filename.tex
pandoc filename.html -t plain -o filename.txt
```

This is the result:

```
Проверка

References

 [1] 

    N. G. Reitman et al. “Транзитная фотомозаика высокого разрешения из
    моделирования на основе изображений: анализ рабочих процессов и
    ошибок”. In: Bulletin of the Seismological Society of America 105
    (2015), pp. 2354–2366.
```